# Minified JS file for react not working inside flask app

Tags: reactjs, flask

I am writing a ReactJS app with a Flask backend. In my `templates` folder, I have an `index.html` file that looks like this:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" />
    <script src="../../app/client.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The `client.min.js` file exists in a different directory called `app`, which I generate by running `webpack`. I call `index.html` using the `render_template` method:

```
from flask import Blueprint
from flask import render_template
welcome = Blueprint('welcome', __name__)
@welcome.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

When I run the flask server and open `localhost:8080`, I see the jquery script loading correctly, but there is an error loading the `client.min.js` file. I see this in the network request header -

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/app/client.min.js
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 NOT FOUND
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8080
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Comment: Is the app directory containing the js file served as static in flask ?

Comment: No, it wasn't earlier. But after reading your comment, I moved all the code in the app directory to under static and changed the script src to just 'client.min.js'. I still see the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't serve templates and have the template load a file from ../../ in flask, you have to define the static folder in flask factory or application to use then in the script tag you have something like `<script src="static/app/app.min.js"></script>`